# Force stop or halt on error

Tags: r, emacs, ess

I was wondering if anyone knew of a good way to get R or ESS to stop executing the rest of the code beyond the point at which an error occurs if I am evaluating a region or buffer (I've only found the opposite request in the help archives). I was looking in the R help files but `option(error=stop)` will only stop execution of the offending function or statement but not those that follow it. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

If R/ESS is hogging up so much compute time that your emacs/ESS is unresponsive to C-c C-c, you can also save it by sending an INTERRUPT signal from the terminal.

First: figure out R's processID  using `top` or `ps`. (mine was 98490
Then:
`kill -2 98490`
That sends an interrupt signal and you get your ESS/Emacs and R session back

Answer (score 5):

[According to the ESS manual](http://ess.r-project.org/Manual/ess.html#index-aborting-S-commands-110), this should work:
`C-c C-c` (comint-interrupt-subjob)
Sends a `Control-C` signal to the ESS process. This has the effect of aborting the current command.

John Fox has a website where he offers a configuration for ESS. In it, he has this function:

```
(defun stop-R ()

"Interrupt R process in lower window."

(interactive)

(select-window win2)

(comint-interrupt-subjob)

(select-window win1))
```

You should be able to add this function to the menu in XEmacs using:

```
(defun R-menu ()

  "Hook to install R menu and sub-menus"

  (add-menu-item '("ESS" "R") "Interrupt computation" 'stop-R
)
)
(add-hook 'ess-mode-hook 'R-menu)
```

You might check out the rest of his configuration file and documentation to see if it interests you. I haven't tried this yet, but I hope that it works for you!

Charlie

Comment: Thank you Charlie - I am familiar with C-c C-c but this is for manually stopping a process in progress, regardless of errors (as I understand it). I may look into modifying eval-region or eval-buffer to call this function when an error occurs...

Answer (score 2):

?break

Only gets you out of loop.

?try

Lets you set up code that might fail and gracefully recover.

Comment: Thanks, but when working interactively I don't want to wrap the line or region in try() or tryCatch() each time, but I suppose that would technically do it...

Comment: Hi crippledlambda. Did you find a solution for your problem in the meanwhile?