# Supress the normal-executed script in ESS command prompt buffer (by C-c, C-b)

Tags: r, ess

Every time I run the whole R script in ESS by C-c, C-b, the entire script shows up in the ESS prompt buffer (which albeit annoying, is out of my current question here [see question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428750/force-stop-or-halt-on-error) ). when the script is relatively large, the flashing page of executed scripts in ESS command prompt not only hide out the problematic codes, but also build up the memory usage in emacs overtime. This has to be solved by iteratively pressing C-x, h, backspace to delete the execution history.

I am just wondering whether there is a way to repress the output of the normal-executed script in ESS command prompt, or other method to get around of this. As a user migrating from Matlab, I do feel this is quite annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to try:

1. C-u before C-c C-b will toggle ess-eval-visibly.  so type `C-u C-c C-b`.
2. Have you tried `C-c C-l` to source the file corresponding to the current buffer?

Comment: Thanks, seems both way is making progress!